# Error de MySQL: A table must have at least 1 column

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, tablas, consola

intento crear unas tablas para una base de datos, pero obtengo el siguiente error que no se como solucionar:

```
ERROR 1113 (42000) at line 27: A table must have at least 1 column
```

El problema al parecer es con la tabla Pelicula_Censura, pero las llaves foráneas al parecer no son tomadas. Gracias de antemano!

```
create database pelisOnly;
use pelisOnly

create table if not exists Pelicula
(
            peliculaID int(5) primary key,
            nombre_pelicula varchar(30),
            nombre_protagonista varchar(30),
            año_lanzamiento int(4)  
);

create table if not exists Censura
(
            censuraID int(5) primary Key,
            nombre_censura varchar(45) 
);

create table if not exists Tipo
(             
            tipoID int(5) primary key,
            nombre_tipo varchar(30) 
);

create table if not exists Pelicula_censura
(
            foreign key(peliculaID) references Pelicula(peliculaID),
            foreign key(censuraID) references Censura(censuraID)
);
```

Comment: debes crear columnas en la tabla. Ahí ya puedes definir un FK que relacione campos en la tabla con la PK de otra tabla. Una FK no crea el campo automáticamente, es un constraint más

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exacto, tu problema es que la tabla Pelicula_Censura no tiene definido los campos. Prueba con lo siguiente:

```
create table if not exists Pelicula_censura
(
    peliculaID int(5) not null,
    censuraID int(5) not null,
    foreign key(peliculaID) references Pelicula(peliculaID),
    foreign key(censuraID) references Censura(censuraID)
);
```

Espero te sirva

Comment: Muchas gracias! Esto solucionó mi problema